# How to Make Different Urls For same viewset in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Serializer in my code like this

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = Model
```

and Viewset like this

```
class SampleViewSet(GenericAPIView):
     serializer_class = SampleSerializer

     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         pass

     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         pass

     def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         pass
```

I have url like this for this viewset

**Url #1:**

```
url(r'^sample/$', SampleViewSet.as_view())
```

This makes url for all methods I have in my viewset like get, post and put etc. I want to make separate url for my get method but using same serializer. This url will look like this

**Url #2:**

```
 url(r'^sample/(?P<model_id>\d+)/$', SampleViewSet.as_view())
```

How can I do this using same Viewset and Serializer? When I write Url #2 in urls.py, Swagger shows me all three type (get, post and put) of methods for that Url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you inherit ViewSet from `viewsets.ViewSet` and map your urls view `DefaultRouter`?

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'sample', SampleViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

It will handle all urls for your. `/sample/:id` now will be available for `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods.
Also if it plain CRUD for your `Sample` model, there is a better solution to use a `viewsets.ModelViewset`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`require_GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_GET) decorator from `django.views.decorators.http` for this, and use it in your URL config:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sample/$', SampleViewSet.as_view()),
    url(r'^sample/(?P<model_id>\d+)/$', require_GET(SampleViewSet.as_view())),
]
```

for more fine tuning there is also a [`require_http_method`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods) decorator which receives allowed methods in its parameters, e.g.:

```
url(r'^sample/(?P<model_id>\d+)/$', require_http_method(['GET', 'DELETE'])(SampleViewSet.as_view()))
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf for details.

Comment: There's also the [`require_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_safe) decorator which is the same as `require_http_method(['GET', 'HEAD'])`